# Admin and ClickOnce C# Visual Studio 2008/2012

Tags: c#

My C# application needs to run with admin privileges however, I cannot publish it due to ClickOnce restrictions.

I have been searching for a resolution to this, however, I have yet to find one that works.

The most common suggestion is to add an installer to the project, however, I don't have seem to have in either my version of Visual Studio 2008 or Visual Studio 2012.

Can anyone offer me any suggestions of how I can publish a C# project with admin privileges?

Comment: Installer projects were deprecated in VS2012.

Comment: Okay,
Sow how would I publish my project with admin privileges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following article describes how to have a ClickOnce application launch itself with admin privilieges - maybe this helps? http://antscode.blogspot.de/2011/02/running-clickonce-application-as.html

Answer (score 0):

[WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) is a (free) tool for creating installation packages.  I do not have any experience with it myself but it seems that you can use WiX for [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) elevation when running the installation.

I did a [search](https://www.google.dk/search?q=wix%20uac%20elevation&aq=1&oq=wix%20uac&aqs=chrome.2.57j0l3.4451&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for WiX and UAC and it seems that lots of people are using WiX when UAC is required - e.g. this article:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/12/13/some-useful-things-i-have-learned-about-windows-installer-and-uac.aspx.